# What is the correct method for comparing sensitivity and specifity of different tests?

Tags: sensitivity-analysis, sensitivity-specificity

What is the correct method of comparing efficiency of different test for one sample of individuals?

1. Are ROC and AUC enough?
2. Comparing of sensitivity and specifity values of the tests with McNemar test?
3. Comparing of AUC values with an apropriate statistical test (any suggestion?)

Comment: F1 score is usually used for this purpose since it averages (harmonically) precision and recall and allows for a single measure so several models can be directly compared.

Comment: Dear @guy Thanks for your prompt reply. But, according to my research on the internet (so my statistical knowledge is limited), F1 score might be better than ROC curves for this purpose but I wonder in case of using ROC curves which method should I use comparing the different test (McNemar or comparing AUC?) or sensitivity ,specificity, PPV NPC values are enough for this.

Comment: It really depends on your case and the meaning of false positives and/or false negatives for your situation. There's no hard and fast rule, you need to judge what measure(s) is appropriate and test / compare around that.